# Kaleidoscope for git difftool

Tags: git, comparison, difftool

I tried using kaleidoscope for `git difftool` to compare two branches.

So I installed [ksdiff](http://www.kaleidoscopeapp.com/ksdiff2) and setted it like follow in my `.gitconfig`

```
 [diff]
     tool = kaleidoscope
 [difftool "kaleidoscope"]
     cmd = ksdiff --changeset $(cd $(dirname "$LOCAL") && pwd)/$(basename "$LOCAL") $(cd $(dirname "$MERGED") && pwd)/$(basename "$MERGED")
```

when running

```
git difftool myBranch otherBranch
```

I Receive the error `cannot use duplicate files within the same file list`

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I found a way to configure it. In Kaleidoscope itself under ***Kaleidoscope*** menu there is a link called ***Integration*** which open a configuration window for several versioning solutions.

[image: Kaleidoscope "Integration" configuration window]

After installing **ksdiff** clicking on ***Configure*** button will add the following lines to your `.gitconfig` file.

```
[diff]
    tool = Kaleidoscope
[difftool "Kaleidoscope"]
  cmd = ksdiff --partial-changeset --relative-path \"$MERGED\" -- \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
[merge]
    tool = Kaleidoscope
[mergetool "Kaleidoscope"]
  cmd = ksdiff --merge --output \"$MERGED\" --base \"$BASE\" -- \"$LOCAL\" --snapshot \"$REMOTE\" --snapshot
  trustExitCode = true
```

then running the following command will open successively each different file

```
git difftool myBranch otherBranch  -y -t Kaleidoscope
```

--

***Notes:***

- `-y` stands to avoid prompting for asking if we want to use Kaleidoscope for difftool for each file. Default answer is "yes".
- `-t Kaleidoscope` is optionnal here as default difftool is already set to `Kaleidoscope` in our `.gitconfig` file.

Comment: In my case I also had to add `[merge]
    tool = Kaleidoscope` to my `.gitconfig`.

Comment: You can also use `[difftool]        prompt = false` (and same for `[mergetool]`) in `.gitconfig` to always "avoid prompting for asking if we want to use Kaleidoscope for difftool for each file".